# cálculo de porcentagem jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho este código e coloquei no jsfiddle  para facilitar a compreensão

http://jsfiddle.net/opeta/L7e73zx2/

Ele faz um cálculo de porcentagens somando no valor do preço da compra e coloca o resultado no preço da venda.
ele funciona se eu colocar um número inteiro no preço de compra, mas em toda a aplicação eu uso o maskmoney e faço cálculos com ele, ficando inviável eu retirar esta máscara.
alguém pode me ajudar nesta questão?

Comment: Qual deveria ser a fórmula do calculo? `Exp: PC + (CE * 0,2) + ST + (IPI * 0,5)`

Comment: seria PV = (PC * CE / 100) + (PC * ST / 100) + (PC * IPI / 100)

Comment: @opeta Eu não entendi a sua dúvida, seja mais claro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

opeta, tenta fazer assim:

P.S.: o $.fn.val é um workaround para poder setar o valor do input apos aplicar a mascara.

```js
var originalVal = $.fn.val;
$.fn.val = function(value) {
    if (typeof value == 'undefined') {
        return originalVal.call(this);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            this.trigger('mask.maskMoney');
        }.bind(this), 100);
        return originalVal.call(this, value);
    }
};

function calcular(event) 
{   
    var inputs = {
        precoCompra: $('#precoCompra'),
        custoempresa: $('#custoempresa'),
        st: $('#st'),
        ipi: $('#ipi'),
        precoVenda: $('#precoVenda')
    };
    var valores  = {
        precoCompra: parseFloat(inputs.precoCompra.val()),
        custoempresa: parseFloat(inputs.custoempresa.val()),
        st: parseFloat(inputs.st.val()),
        ipi: parseFloat(inputs.ipi.val()),
        precoVenda: 0.0
    };  
    
    valores.custoempresa = isNaN(valores.custoempresa) ? 0.0 : valores.precoCompra * (valores.custoempresa / 100);
    valores.st = isNaN(valores.st) ? 0.0 : valores.precoCompra * (valores.st / 100);
    valores.ipi = isNaN(valores.ipi) ? 0.0 : valores.precoCompra * (valores.ipi / 100);
    
    valores.precoVenda = valores.precoCompra + valores.custoempresa + valores.st + valores.ipi;
    inputs.precoVenda.val(valores.precoVenda.toFixed(2));
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var inputs = $(".money").maskMoney();
  
    var inputs = $("input[name='custoempresa'], input[name='st'], input[name='ipi'], input[name='precoCompra']");
    inputs.on({
        //keypress: calcular,
        keyup: calcular,
        //keydown: calcular,
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney/master/dist/jquery.maskMoney.js"></script>
<div class="control-group">
    <label for="precoCompra" class="control-label">Preço de Compra<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input id="precoCompra" class="money" type="text" name="precoCompra" value=""  />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label for="custoempresa" class="control-label">Custo Empresa<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input id="custoempresa" type="text" name="custoempresa" value=""  />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label for="st" class="control-label">Subs. Tributária<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input id="st" type="text" name="st" value=""  />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label for="ipi" class="control-label">IPI<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input id="ipi" type="text" name="ipi" value=""  />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label for="precoVenda" class="control-label">Preço de Venda<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input id="precoVenda" class="money" type="text" name="precoVenda" value=""  />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: aqui esta dando certo mais quando jogo na aplicação por algum motivo ta duplicando os número. se digito 33 no preço de compra fica 33.33 :(

Comment: descobri o motivo e já corrigi, muito obrigado pela sua ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, segue minha versão do seu código(<s>tava terminando de montar quando o @Toby postou a resposta rs</s>)

Acredito que o mais fácil seria utilizar o evento `onkeyup` para receber os valores dos `inputs`, você pode realizar a conta de forma direta:

```
  var PV = (PC * CE / 100) + (PC * ST / 100) + (PC * IPI / 100);
```

```js
(function($) {
  $("#precoCompra").maskMoney({thousands:'', decimal:'.', allowZero:true, suffix: ' R$'});
  $("#custoempresa").maskMoney({thousands:'', decimal:'.', allowZero:true, suffix: ' R$'});
  $("#st").maskMoney({thousands:'', decimal:'.', allowZero:true, suffix: ' R$'});
  $("#ipi").maskMoney({thousands:'', decimal:'.', allowZero:true, suffix: ' R$'});
})(jQuery);

function calcular(){
  var PC = $("#precoCompra").val().substring(0, $("#precoCompra").val().length-2);
  var CE = $("#custoempresa").val().substring(0, $("#custoempresa").val().length-2);
  var ST = $("#st").val().substring(0, $("#st").val().length-2);
  var IPI = $("#ipi").val().substring(0, $("#ipi").val().length-2);
  console.log(PC,CE,ST,IPI);
  var PV = (PC * CE / 100) + (PC * ST / 100) + (PC * IPI / 100);
  $("#precoVenda").html("R$ "+PV);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/javascripts/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>
Preço de Compra* <br/><input id="precoCompra" class="money" type="text" name="precoCompra" onkeyup="calcular()"/>
<br/>
Custo Empresa* <br/><input id="custoempresa" type="text" name="custoempresa" onkeyup="calcular()"/>
<br/>
Subs. Tributária* <br/><input id="st" type="text" name="st" onkeyup="calcular()"/>
<br/>
IPI* <br/><input id="ipi" type="text" name="ipi" onkeyup="calcular()"/>
<br/>
Preço de Venda: <br/>
<label id="precoVenda" class="money" name="precoVenda"></label>
```